# default font color, background, etc

Tags: browser, pdf, colors

Is there a way to read PDFs in a font and font color of your choosing?

Is there a way to view all your websites in a web background of your choosing? I remember in Windows Opera there was a way to view the webpage in certain color and font with a shortkey. I wish the background could be certain pictures, no matter which site I visit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason people create pdf's is to force users to view a document in a particular format. (Colors, fonts, spacing, breaks etc.)

PDF readers that don't display the document that way aren't doing what they're supposed to do.

You could try using the selection tool and copy/paste into Word or something of the sort, to modify as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

the **[Blackout](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13443)** Firefox addon allows you to change the colour scheme of a website.

you can choose from predefined built-in colour schemes or configure your colour preferenes.